# Passing parameters by reference in CreateInstance

Tags: c#, ref, createinstance

*[Edit: I've added a lot of detail to this question to make it clearer why I need to pass the enumerator by reference]*

I'm writing some code that parses a list built up of commands and parameters.  Not all commands have the same number of parameters.  For instance, the list could be -

```
command1,
100,
command2,
54,
42,
71,
command3,
10,
31,
command1,
82,
command3,
102,
87
```

(Note that some commands may have parameters that are non-integers)

I'm iterating through the list of data using a List enumerator.  Each command has its own class that is able to parse the command's parameters from the list (and do a series of other activities relating to the command which aren't needed for this cut down example).

I have a dictionary which connects the commands to their classes -

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
    { "command1", typeof(Command1Class) },
    { "command2", typeof(Command2Class) },
    { "command3", typeof(Command3Class) },
};
```

So my basic parsing loop is as follows -

```
var enumerator = data.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var command = (string)enumerator.Current;
    codeBlock.AddBlock((Block)Activator.CreateInstance(map[command], new object[] { enumerator }));
}
```

(All command classes derive from the same base type, Block)

So in the constructor of each command class, it can parse how ever many parameters that command takes and, upon return to the main loop, the enumerator will have moved on through those parameters.

For example -

```
class Command1Class : Block
{
    string param;

    public Command1Class(ref List<object>.Enumerator enumerator)
    {
        enumerator.MoveNext();
        param = (string)enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

But what I'm finding it that the enumerator is only modified locally in the constructor.  So upon returning from the constructor, the enumerator is still pointing to the command rather than having moved on through how ever many parameters that command requires.

If I do this non-dynamically using the following style, it works as expected with the enumerator pointing to the next command when it returns from the constructor -

```
new SomeClass(ref enumerator)
```

So I'm wondering why my code with CreateInstance is not working as expected and how am I able to do this dynamically?

Comment: What exactly you expect to happen?

Comment: It is unlcear what "is expected".

Comment: You're both right.  I've added a lot more information to make the reason for doing this and the expected outcome much clearer

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance is not able to pass `ref` or `out` parameters to constructors in such a way that the changes propagate outside. The only way to do this *dynamically* would be to generate the IL to do it. However, since you can't call this IL dynamically like this either, you need to standardize on the constructor arguments for the types you want to construct such that you can wrap this in a method.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think it's not exactly true that "Activator.CreateInstance is not able to pass ref or out parameters to constructors in such a way that the changes propagate outside". You pass all arguments as `object[]` array, and elements in this array _will_ be changed if respected parameters are passed by ref or out. So changes will be visible outside, just not in a way one might expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite many issues with your approach because `Enumerator` is struct (so, value type). It means (among other things) that it gets copied under many circumstances, for example if you remove `ref` keyword:

```
public Command1Class(List<object>.Enumerator enumerator)
```

And then pass your enumerator - it will be copied and enumerator inside `Command1Class` constructor is not the same instance as outside. You noticed this and pass enumerator by reference in constructor, but the same problem bites you again when you do this:

```
(Block)Activator.CreateInstance(map[command], new object[] { enumerator })
```

You pass enumerator inside `object[]` array (as expected by `CreateInstance`), and this again makes a copy. It's more clear like this:

```
var args = new object[] { enumerator };
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Command1Class), args);
```

When you create `args` array - it already contains a copy of `enumerator`, not the same instance. Now this copy is passed by reference to your constructor and is indeed advanced, which you can verify like this:

```
var args = new [] { enumerator };
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Command1Class), args);
// assign copy back to original value
enumerator = (List<object>.Enumerator) args[0];  
// now enumerator is advanced as expected
```

Actually the same will happen if `enumerator` were reference type, because when you put it in array to pass arguments to `Activator.CreateInstance` - it no longer the same variable (it points to the same object in memory, but pointer itself is different).

So your approach is very fragile and probably you should redesign it. If you'd like to stick with it - do not pass anything to constructor but instead create method at `Block` class:

```
public void Init(ref List<object>.Enumerator enumerator)
```

Then call it without reflection.

Comment: Excellent explanation - thank you very much. Using a separate Init function seems like a nice solution so I'll go ahead with that.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ref you need pass list instead of ref enumerator and call getEnumerator inside the constuctor.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(List<object> list)
    {
        var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
        enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<object>();
        var someClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SomeClass), 
            new object[] { list = list });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've added a lot more detail to the original question to make it a lot clearer as to why I need to pass the enumerator by reference as well as the outcome I'm expecting